# Save icon in toolbar in v9

Tags: interface

In previous versions of MMA there was a 'Save" icon in the toolbar when you do the "Show Toolbar" from the "Window" menu. This is not present in v9. Anybody know how to get it back?

Comment: Wow... so there are people who press the save icon instead of Ctrl-S? :D I couldn't find a way to restore it, but I wouldn't be surprised if the decision to remove it was made because these days no one ever uses it, and most folks don't even know what that icon really stands for...

Comment: @Hypnotoad I miss that icon as well. Must be a generation thing.

Comment: Yeah, I'm old and use(d) the icon.

Comment: The only way I  see is creating a `Palette` with a 'Save' button and possibly other menu commands.

Comment: There is a toolbar??

Comment: @halirutan Me too... this post was what pointed me to the existence of a toolbar! It _might_ have been handy when I was starting out and learning to use the different styles.

Comment: @PeterR I'he searched for all system files for "EditBar", because when you click on "Show Toolbar" the notebook option `WindowToolbars->{"EditBar"}` is set. No luck. Wouldn't it be a possibility to [build your own toolbar](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IntroductionToToolbars.html)? I mean, this looks like not so much work.

Comment: @halirutan the file "EditBar" does not seem to exist in version 8 either.

Answer (score 2):

As @halirutan posted in the comments of the original question one can build one's own toolbar.  The documentation is quite clear and provides nice examples.  As he stated, It can be found [here.](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IntroductionToToolbars.html)

However, I imagine that some might need help\don't want to take the time.  And since I can't sleep, I've built a quick tool bar that includes some common options.

```
save = Button[ImageResize[(**your "save" image here**), {26, 19}], 
   FrontEndTokenExecute["Save"], Appearance -> None, 
   ImageSize -> {27, 20}];
saveas = Button[ImageResize[(**your "save as" image here**), {26, 19}], 
   FrontEndTokenExecute["SaveRename"], Appearance -> None, 
   ImageSize -> {27, 20}];
print = Button[ImageResize[(**your "print" image here**), {26, 19}], 
   FrontEndTokenExecute["PrintDialog"], Appearance -> None, 
   ImageSize -> {27, 20}];
labels = Style[#, 9, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"] & /@ {"Save", 
    "Save As", "Print"};
CreateWindow[
  DockedCells -> 
   Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[Grid[{{save, saveas, print}, labels}]]], 
    "DockedCell"]];
```

This will create a new window with the toolbar at the top, though only in the new window.

I did a bit of poking around and found where v9 defines its menu.  I imagine you might be able to edit that file to add a permanent toolbar, but I'm unwilling to mess with it on my system and I wouldn't advise messing with it in general when the above code works nicely.